# why tailwind css intellisense not working in next js app using ts?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, intellisense

[this is my tailwind.config.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5PKH.png)

I tried looking at yt tutorials but nothing has worked so far i also have the tailwind.config.ts file in my next js app it still does'nt work maybe it has something to do with the settings!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the extension: Tailwind CSS IntelliSense?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use the default config file that Next provides upon creating a new project with Tailwind. Some things to verify:

- Ensure that you have properly installed and activated the [TailwindCSS Intellisense Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss). Then, after:

  - Check the `editor.quickSuggestions`

> By default VS Code will not trigger completions when editing "string" content, for example within JSX attribute values. Updating the editor.quickSuggestions setting may improve your experience:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "strings": "on"
}
```

- Ensure that Tailwind itself is installed in the `node_modules` directory at the root of your project, in conjuction with it being listed in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.
- The config file should be (and it seems like it is from the screenshot) located at the root of the project with the name of `tailwind.config.ts`.
- From the [official documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#troubleshooting):

> Make sure your VS Code settings aren’t causing your Tailwind config file to be hidden/ignored, for example via the `files.exclude` or `files.watcherExclude` settings.

- Lastly, do post the output of the `Tailwind CSS: Show Output` command (By default, you can open the command palette with Ctr+Shift+P) for more info regarding the initialization of Tailwind. It should Load the config file, postcss and Tailwind and then build it.